# Powershell: Split-Path Not Working in -Replace

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to pre-process C code, replacing
`#include "../../abc/efg/hij.h"` with 
`"hij.h"`.

I use command

```
'#include "../../abc/efg/hij.h"' -replace '(#include\s+)(".*\w+\.h")',"$(Split-Path -Leaf `$2)"
```

To do the replacement. However, no matter how I tried (use single-/double- quote, `$()`, and other methods), the final string (I did not `Set-Content` yet, just want to see the result in standard output) is still `"../../abc/efg/hij.h"`.

When I run `Split-Path -Leaf "../../abc/efg/hij.h"`, the result is `hij.h`, which is correct.

Can some one please tell me why this happens? Thank you very much!

Comment: Separating paths can be done completely with regex, but I think the more interesting problem is how to manipulate the match groups using PS commands prior to replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Seems weird that you are doing path parsing with regex, but then trying to use `Split-Path` to do it with a commandlet as well. Why not do the replace entirely with regexes?

Get rid of the bit you don't want by capturing it and replacing it with nothing:

```
PS C:\> '#include "../../abc/efg/hij.h"' -replace '(?<=#include\s+")(.*/)(?=\w+\.h")'
#include "hij.h"
```

or keep the bit you do want by capturing it and putting it into a new line:

```
PS C:\> '#include "../../abc/efg/hij.h"' -replace '#include\s+".*/(.*\.h)"','#include "$1"'
#include "hij.h"
```

Comment: Yes, later I did like this. Just wondering why it happens. New to Powershell, and still confused. Your solution is the better way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is that the `-replace` operator matches the regex and performs the replacement atomically.  It provides no method to run any PowerShell code in between the two operations.

In your code, the scriptblock `(Split-Path -Leaf $2)` evaluates first, before the regex has been matched.  The result of that scriptblock (`$null`, the empty string, or an exception depending on what value the variable `$2` holds) is then passed to `-replace`, with observed result.

What you want is to be able to run a PowerShell command in between matching the regex and replacing it.  One way to do this is to use `-match` to match the regular expression, and then build up your replacement string using the matches in the `$matches` variable.

```
$oldLine -match '#include\s+"(.*\w+\.h)"'
$newLine = '#include "{0}"' -f (split-path -leaf $matches[1])
```

Optionally you can do the replacement using the `-replace` operator, rather than building the whole line from scratch.  However, because it evaluates the regex again, it can lead to performance problems for large input files.

Comment: Your answer is very inspiring, thank you! I finally have something naive: 
 get-content a.h | ForEach-Object {$_ -match '#include\s+"(.*\w+\.h)"' > $null; if ($matches[1]) { "#include `"$(split-path -leaf $matches[1])`"" } else { $_ } } | add-content b.h; Move-Item -Force b.h a.h